# integrating Styled-Component with Selenium Locators

Tags: css, reactjs, selenium, python-unittest, styled-components

I'm going to run automation testing on a website using react Styled-Components. As styled component changing the CSS selectors frequently, my question is:
What's an alternative to select an element contains a dynamic CSS style generated by Styled-Component?

I've used `X-path`, but not all elements are good candidate for x-path

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution. Hope it help you.

**1. Use HTML5 attribute like data-testid, or data-what-ever-you-like**

For example: (view live on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-wozniak-dkl3q))

```js
import React from "react";
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

const BorderBox = styled.div`
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #cacaca;
`;
const Button = styled.button`
  color: palevioletred;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
  border: 2px solid palevioletred;
  border-radius: 3px;
`;

// A new component based on Button, but with some override styles
const TomatoButton = styled(Button)`
  color: tomato;
  border-color: tomato;
`;

export const MyContainer = React.memo(props => {
  return (
    <BorderBox data-testid="myContainer">
      <TomatoButton data-testid="tomatoButton">Tomato Button</TomatoButton>
      <Button data-testid="normalButton">Normal Button </Button>
    </BorderBox>
  );
});
```

**2. Use xpath to query your component:**

```
$x("//div[@data-testid='myContainer']") 

$x("//div[@data-testid='myContainer']/button[@data-testid='tomatoButton']")
```